# Android app won't store data in a database

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, xml

## ---BACKGROUND---

*I'm a total noob, the definition of a beginner programmer. Please, when responding, keep that in mind. :)*

## ---STORY---

So in short, my android application i'm working on is supposed to have a registration/login form and the main content "behind" that. Basically, the user in order to get access to the application and it's content first must register himself an account, the account details should get stored in a database, and after that at the login form when the user is trying to sign in with their believed username and password the application should check whether the username/password he/she put in is right or not(obviously, if both are right he gets past the login form and gets access to the content, if not, then he gets reminded that either the password, username or both he tried logging in with was wrong).

## ---PROBLEM---

After I put in all the details needed at the registration form(firstname,lastname,username,password,email) and click the button, my app, as it should, starts a new activity(the login form), where I should be able to sign in with the username and password I earlier chose. But, the problem is, no matter how hard I try, the database just won't get updated with any of the details(username, firstname, lastname, pw and email). The interesting part is that I'm following a tutorial https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLe60o7ed8E-TztoF2K3y4VdDgT6APZ0ka to make the app, and even with the original files provided by the maker of that tutorial series, my app still won't update the database after the user completes the registration form. The hosting company I'm using is
        https://www.siteground.com/ .

## ---TLDR---

My Android Application should have the content hidden behind a registration/login form, if the user successfully registers he should be able to 
sign in with the username and password he chose. The details the application asked for during the registration process (firstname, lastname, username, password, email) should be stored in a database. The problem is that after filling in the registration form
the database won't get updated.

## LAST BUT NOT LEAST, THE CODE:

**RegisterActivity.java**
`

public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    final EditText etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFirstName);
    final EditText etLastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etLastName);
    final EditText etFirstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
    final EditText etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    final EditText etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
    final Button RegisterButton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.RegisterButton2);

    RegisterButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String firstname = etFirstName.getText().toString();
            final String lastname = etLastName.getText().toString();
            final String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
            final String password = etPassword.getText().toString();
            final String email = etEmail.getText().toString();

            Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>(){
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                        if (success){
                            Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                            RegisterActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this);
                            builder.setMessage("Register Failed")
                                    .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                    .create()
                                    .show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

            RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(firstname, lastname, username, password, email, responseListener);
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(RegisterActivity.this);
            queue.add(registerRequest);
        }
    });
}
```

`

**RegisterRequest.java**

```
public class RegisterRequest extends StringRequest {
private static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL = "http://wearelifemap.com/Register.php";
private Map<String, String> params;

public RegisterRequest(String firstname, String lastname, String username, String password, String email, Response.Listener<String> listener){
    super(Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
    params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("firstname", firstname);
    params.put("lastname", lastname);
    params.put("username", username);
    params.put("password", password);
    params.put("email", email);
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getParams() {
    return params;
}
```

**Register.php**

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "wearelif_xtreme", "abc123",     "wearelif_user2");

$firstname = $_POST["firstname"];
$lastname = $_POST["lastname"];
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$email    = $_POST["email"];
$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO user (firstname, lastname, username, password, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "sssss", $firstname, $lastname, $username, $password, $email);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = true;  

echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: Did you chk the permissions for the MySQL userid? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-grants.html

Comment: And mysqli error checking: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an example of similar thing for saving username and password, try modifying according to your idea. The process is very similar. 
In this I have used "Volley" for Networking Calls. Make sure once you google "what is volley in android?".

```
//Layout of Activity
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="2dp"
tools:context="com.test.test.ScreenOne">


<EditText
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/etUsername"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
    android:hint="username"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/etPassword"
    android:hint="password"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etUsername"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Login"
    android:id="@+id/bLogin"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etPassword"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Save"
    android:id="@+id/bSave"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bLogin"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="42dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity has 2 buttons and 2 EditText, Login button login via server and Save button saves your data in server:

```
package com.test.test;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class ScreenOne extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String URL_LOGIN = "http://YOUT_IP_ADDRESS(save file in xampp/any local server)/login.php";
private static final String URL_SAVE = "http://YOUR_IP_ADDRESS(save file in xampp/any local server)/save.php";
private EditText username;
private EditText password;
private Button login;
Button save;
String name;
String pass;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.screen_one);

    username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);

    (login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLogin)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            request();
        }
    });

    (save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSave)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            saveRequest();
        }
    });
}

private void saveRequest() {
    //get string data from edittext field,in your case take from name, email, password.......
    name = username.getText().toString().trim();
    pass = password.getText().toString().trim();

    //show progressdialog while loading data
    final ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    mDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    mDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    mDialog.show();

    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_SAVE,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    //responce from server, dismiss dialog and print responce in a toast message.
                    mDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(ScreenOne.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    mDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(ScreenOne.this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> key = new HashMap<>();
            //map value to match in your php script, update with yours e.g. name,lastname,email.....
            key.put("username", name);
            key.put("password", pass);
            return key;
        }
    };

    NetworkCalls.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);
}

private void request() {
    name = username.getText().toString().trim();
    pass = password.getText().toString().trim();
    final ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    mDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    mDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    mDialog.show();

    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_LOGIN,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    mDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(ScreenOne.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    username.setText("");
                    password.setText("");
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    mDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(ScreenOne.this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> key = new HashMap<>();
            //map the username and password to match with the php script so the user can pass his login values here
            key.put("username", name);
            key.put("password", pass);
            return key;
        }
    };

    NetworkCalls.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);
 }
}
```

Singleton class for Volley request:

```
import android.content.Context;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

/**
 * Created by W4R10CK on 14-09-2016.
 */
public class NetworkCalls {
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private static Context context;

    private static NetworkCalls ourInstance = new NetworkCalls();

    public static NetworkCalls getInstance() {
        return ourInstance;
    }

    private NetworkCalls() {
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue(){
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context.getApplicationContext());
        return requestQueue;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> request){
        getRequestQueue().add(request);
    }
}
```

API to call server:

```
 //conn.php for connection (file one)
<?php
$host = "localhost"; //update with yours
$user = "root"; //update the phpmyadmin username
$pass = ""; //update with your phpmyadmin password
$db_name = "hello"; //replace with your db name

$con = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$db_name);

if($con -> connect_error){
echo "Connection error";
}   


//save.php(file two)
<?php
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
require_once('conn.php');

//here user is one table with username and password field to save the data coming from user to server. Make sure you replace with your own needs.
$sql = "INSERT INTO user (username, password) VALUES ('$username','$password')";

if($con -> query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "User added";
}
//$con -> close();
?>
?>

//login.php(file three)
<?php
require_once('conn.php');

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

if(mysqli_fetch_array($result) == NULL){
echo "Invalid Cred.";
}else{
echo "Success";
}

$con->close();
?>
```

Lastly create one DB named **hello** and table in localhost **user** with 2 fields **username**, **password**.